# Graph theory for a simple graph confusion.

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph theory question I am struggling to get my head around:

"A *simple graph* $G$ has $6$ vertices and their degrees are $2d, 2d, 2d+1, 2d+1, 2d+1$ and $3d-1$ where $d$ is an integer. By considering the *sum* of the degrees, show that $d$ is *even*.

So, I read up that for a simple graph the "sum of the degrees is 2 times the number of edges" and I know the definition of a simple graph. How does the fact that the sum of degrees being $13d+2$ show that $d$ is even, my textbook just shows the summation and says "hence even"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $d$ is odd so is $13d+2$, but we already said the sum of the degrees must be even.

Comment: Ok, I may be over complicating this one. So the fact they said "show that d is even" implies that is definitely is? Is it a bit of a daft question then?

Comment: No, before you do the work to find the sum of degrees is $13d+2$ you don't know $d$ is even.  Once you do it, it becomes a simple statement based on the known properties of odd and even numbers.  It actually doesn't matter that the graph is simple.  The handshaking lemma, as this is called, applies to all graphs.

Comment: Then what stops $d$ from being odd?

Comment: If $d=1,$ for example, $13d+2=15$ is odd.  We said the sum of degrees had to be even, so this is not possible.

Comment: When you say "We said the sum of degrees had to be even" are we getting this information from the question asked? I am definitely overthinking this.

Comment: No, it comes from the handshaking lemma.  The sum of degrees corresponds to the number of ends of edges.  Each edge has two ends, so contributes two to the sum.  The sum must therefore be even for any graph.

Comment: Of course! I finally understand it now, apologies for being slow, this area of maths I somewhat struggle with. Many thanks!